# Change variable outside of function's scope

Tags: javascript

So I have the current code:

```
exports.retrieveMessages = function retrieveMessages () {
    var messages = [];
    User_Message.find({}, function(err, msgs) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // object of all the users
        msgs.forEach(function(entry) {
            messages.push({username: entry.username, message: entry.message});
            //console.log(entry.message);
            //console.log(entry.username);
        });
    });
    console.log(messages);
    return messages;
}
```

Somehow messages is still empty after User_messages.find(). Is there any way to push the results onto the messages variable? I verified that if I move the console.log(messages) into the foreach loop, it will actually print things, meaning the messages I see inside the foreach loop is different than the one outside.

Also, is this because the messages inside the function is a local variable thus I am actually pushing this onto a different variable?

Comment: try to declare the var messages = []; variable above this line - exports.retrieveMessages = function retrieveMessages () {

Comment: your code looks to be correct and i think should be working ...

Comment: looks like you might be dealing with an asynchronous method, use a callback based method instead of returning value

Comment: This question has been asked many times in many forms. Basically, `messages` will be not available until it is, well, available. It's available only after the callback has been called, not right after the asynchronous call was issued, which is when you're trying to look at it.

Comment: I am fairly sure @ArunPJohny is correct. But to answer your question about scope: No, `messages` is available to the "inner" functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that `User_Message.find` is asynchronous. It's not until it returns and calls the inner callback that `messages` will have these new values pushed into it, which is after the outer function, `retrieveMessages` returns.

Any code that depends on the messages returned will have to be invoked by the callback passed to `User_Message.find`.

Answer (score 0):

Your User_Messages.find is async. If it was synchronous you could do what you are doing. But since it is asynchronous you will have to do it this way.

```
exports.retrieveMessages = function retrieveMessages (callback) {
    var messages = [];
    User_Message.find({}, function(err, msgs) {
        if (err) {
           callback(err);
        } else {
          // object of all the users
          msgs.forEach(function(entry) {
            messages.push({username: entry.username, message: entry.message});
          });
          callback(null, messages);
        }
    });
}
```

Then when using your retriveMessages functions you can do this

```
retrieveMessages(function(err, messages){
  // handle err
  if(err){
    throw err; //or you can show friendly error message to user and log it.
  }
  //now you can access messages
  console.log(messages);
});
```

I highly recommend this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ for the beginners who are confused about event loop and asynchronous nature of js.